# Why do knex migration examples pass the Promise constructor as a second argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

Knex uses migration files to apply or roll back database structural changes. To create a new migration file, for example, one can use the cli:

```
knex migrate:make migration_name
```

This generates a file in the `/migrations` directory containing:

```
exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {

};

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {

};
```

My question is, why is this passing `Promise` as an argument?  I see that knex makes heavy internal use of Bluebird, and [passes `Promise` to the migration](https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/migrate/index.js#L349).  Is this, then, a vestige from pre-`Promise` ubiquity?  Or... is it that to purposefully overwrite the es6 implementation so it can make use of nonstandard methods like `tap` and `spread`?

Any clarity would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly it was originally added there because `es5` didn't have global `Promise` object.

It is not a documented feature, but for now the `Promise` passed to migration script is `bluebird` promise (https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/blob/master/src/migrate/index.js#L327).

However safest choice for future compatibility is to import promise from `bluebird` by yourself instead of using the one passed to the migration if you like to use special functions from `bluebird`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight.  That was my first thought as well, but, with respect, it doesn't really withstand scrutiny.  In the first part, these are function expressions, not calls; the value of `Promise`, thus, will be overwritten by the second argument to the module's `up` or `down` functions.  Having digested the code base more, it seems that it was an early adopter of `Promise`s using `bluebird`, and now it internally relies upon nonstandard methods and must overwrite the native implementation in order to work.  Fascinating.

Answer (score -1):

The main benefit of promises are the ability to catch thrown errors without crashing the node app, making your code behave like a .try / .catch / .finally in synchronous code.

```
knex.select('name')
.from('users')
.where('id', '>', 20)
.andWhere('id', '<', 200)
.limit(10)
.offset(x)
.then(function(rows) {
  return _.pluck(rows, 'name');
})
.then(function(names) {
  return knex.select('id').from('nicknames').whereIn('nickname', names);
})
.then(function(rows) {
  console.log(rows);
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.error(error)
});
```

refer: http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-Promises

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that's not what I was asking.  I was asking why specifically `Promise` is conventionally passed to migration functions.